# How to choose list with closest numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a  problem from my work. I have a list of numbers. Now some numbers on the list are given, but in some instances I can choose between the numbers. I need to have a list with smallest possible differences (have the numbers be as close to each other as possible). Is there an equasion to ensure it?
The list is following 67,67,82,25,67,33,33,82. The two sets where I have a choices (have to choose one of each) are 44,11,29,41 and 13,23,33